# jquery progress bar to show upload file progress

Tags: jquery, html, upload, progress-bar

I want to use progress bar to show file upload progress.
I'm currently using the following code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.progressbar.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#spaceused1").progressBar();
});
```

HTML:

```
<span class="progressBar" id="spaceused1">25%</span>

<a href="#" onclick="$('#spaceused1').progressBar(20);">20</a>
<a href="#" onclick="$('#spaceused1').progressBar(40);">40</a>
<a href="#" onclick="$('#spaceused1').progressBar(80);">80</a>
```

It works fine when i click on the above links. But now how can i use to show the file upload progress?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use some kind of Flash uploader, as this is the only way to get progress notifications from JavaScript. There's a good library for this called [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/), for which there is a jQuery wrapper [here](http://blogs.bigfish.tv/adam/2009/06/14/swfupload-jquery-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use something that has the capability of assessing how much of a file has been uploaded already - the flash solution is a possibility but perl is also capable.

[uber uploader](http://uber-uploader.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Ok it means i'll have to use uber uploader for this. Now tell me if i have post large data to other page, what should i use to show progress of data posted. In other words i'm running a php script which generates the output in for loop when the data is posted to that. This proces takes around 2 min. Now tell which progress bar should i use for that?

Comment: with uber uploader you actually post your data to the perl script - it then uses ajax calls to get the amount uploaded.  you can then set the perl script to redirect on success.